# geom_text with stacked geom_bar - how to make them compatible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
    filter(row_number() < 51) %>% 
    select(carrier, distance) %>% 
    group_by(carrier) %>% 
    summarise(distance = sum(distance)) %>% 
    mutate(prop = distance/sum(distance))
```

With the data above I would like to make a stacked `geom_bar` and then add percentage values with `geom_text`. However, the labels of geom_text doesn't refer to subsequent layers of `geom_bar` (see below).

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = 1, y = prop)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = carrier), stat = 'identity') +
    coord_flip() + theme_void() + theme(legend.position = 'top') +
    labs(fill = '') +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) + 
    scale_fill_viridis_d() + 
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(prop, 3) * 100,"%")), 
                 position = position_stack(vjust = 0), size = 2)
```

[image]

Btw. The second issue is that legend above the plot has no margin from the top of document - I think the issue is connected with usage of `theme_void`, but how can I make a slight margin before a legend?

Comment: "the labels of geom_text doesn't refer to subsequent layers of geom_bar" Can you explain this in more detail? It's hard to read the labels on the chart and I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: the issue is pretty clear while looking on an attached graphic - on a green part should be a label with `39.1%` but there are four labels with lower percentage..

Comment: The labels are hard to read over the darker bars in order to see exactly what's going on. I don't have `nycflights13` installed, and it's better to give detail on the problem here than to have to install a package in order to read the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  filter(row_number() < 51) %>% 
  select(carrier, distance) %>% 
  group_by(carrier) %>% 
  summarise(distance = sum(distance)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(carrier)) %>%
  mutate(prop = distance/sum(distance),
         pos = cumsum(prop)-prop/2) 


ggplot(data, aes(x = 1, y = prop)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = carrier), stat = 'identity')  +
  coord_flip() + theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        plot.margin = margin(20,1,1,1,'pt')) +
  labs(fill = '') +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d() + 
  geom_text(aes(x= 1, y= pos,label = paste0(round(prop, 3) * 100,"%")), size = 2)
```

You can fix the margin issue using `plot.margin` and you can manually calculate the correct y position of the label using `pos = cumsum(prop)-prop/2` to place the label in the middle of the bar. As your data is arranged in alphabetical order in the plot, I've had to also sort the data before calculating the position.

Comment: Thanks. Works ok on the example data, but on my original data (which I cannot share) I have the layers of `geom_bar` and `geom_text` in the exact opposite order - do you know what may be a problem here?

Comment: the position is calculated based on the order of the bars. Here they were alphabetical from right to left. Try `arrange(carrier)` in place of `arrange(desc(carrier))`. Otherwise the order might depend on the levels if your data is `factor`